# How to do an Apache HTTP server virtual host blanket redirect with exceptions

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am running an Apache HTTP server that accepts requests for my domain. Lets call it www.mydomain.com. I have several sites that run under this domain and I have virtual hosts set up for each one that forwards the user depending upon with URL they use. Examples would be a.mydomain.com, b.mydomain.com, etc. I am aware that this may not have been the best way to accomplish this goal considering there are over 100 virtual hosts, but it is something I have inhertited and.. to put it short.. it works. Now on to my problem.

I have recently been tasked with shutting down most of the sites running under the domain. The sites that are shut down have been redirected to one page on my new domain (www.mynewdomain.com). What I have done is changed each of the virtual hosts from something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName a.mydomain.com
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule  ^/$ /SiteA [PT]
</VirtualHost>
```

to this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName a.mydomain.com
  Redirect permanent / http://www.mynewdomain.com/replacement
</VirtualHost>
```

So now I have a list of 100 hosts that all redirect to the same place. What I need to know is if there exists a way to tell the system to redirect all sites at *.mydomain.com to my new page except certain ones. So some entry like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName *.mydomain.com
  Redirect permanent / http://www.mynewdomain.com/replacement
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName h.mydomain.com
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule  ^/$ /SiteH [PT]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName v.mydomain.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule  ^/$ /SiteV [PT]
</VirtualHost>
```

Which means that every URL you see will go to "http://www.mynewdomain.com/replacement" except "h.mydomain.com" and "v.mydomain.com". The virtual hosts for "h" and "v" must still be intact because I have RewriteRules for each that must continue to work (additional rewriterules not seen in my examples).

Thanks in advance for the assistance!